# How can I remove all password requirements from a PDF?

Tags: pdf

Pls see below. I already entered the password to open and get inside the PDF. I then clicked on Protect, Encrypt, Remove Password. But THAT password I entered, isn't the "Permissions Password". It doesn't work when I typed it below.

If you recommend software, ***please specify if free*. I prefer free.**

Please don't just advise me to ask the author. Presume the author doesn't reply to emails, or refuses to remove the password.

[image]

Comment: Ask the author. Seems like the author of this PDF encrypt the document (open password) and also lock with different password the option to remove open password

Comment: Assume the author doesn't reply to emails, or refuses to remove the password.

Comment: In such case you should enter the open password every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **qpdf** which is a open source command line tool for manipulating and analysing pdf files.

https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf/releases

To create a pdf without password protection use the following command.

`qpdf --decrypt --password=abcdef encrypted.pdf output.pdf`

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution would be to print to a PDF printer, Microsoft's one does the job for me in these situations.

Another option would be to use something other than Adobe's Acrobat tools.

Check out:

- [PDF-XChange Editor](https://pdf-xchange.eu/pdf-xchange-editor/index.htm) a free editor that might allow you to modify the properties you need.
- [NAPS2](https://www.naps2.com/) - This one is a scanner tool that allows you to manipulate and author PDFs.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DocDocGoose](https://docdocgoose.huey.xyz/), a gratis and open source web app, to remove edit restrictions from a protected PDF. This does not require you to install any software, and the processing will occur on your computer.

Using DocDocGoose is probably better than printing to a PDF printer, because DocDocGoose will preserve the text layer in your PDF instead of 'flattening' it and converting everything to an image. If you use DocDocGoose, you will be able select/edit/highlight text in the resultant PDF.

Disclaimer: I am the author of this tool.

Answer (score 0):

This method works for MacOS.

1. Open the file in Preview.app.
2. Click `File > Export...`
3. Click the checkbox `Create Linearized PDF`.
4. Save, it should now have the password removed.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Following method worked for me.

- Open the PDF in the browser Chrome/Mozila
- Now add password to open the PDF
- Now Click on PRINT icon
- Select Save As PDF option.
- Click on Save
- It will save the PDF without password. Using this way we do not need to remove the password using third parties.

Comment: The only problem with this method is that the resultant pdf is not text, its an image